# Need code to run macro in excel every 15 minutes, but only if user has File open

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a project to update production notes in a manufacturing schedule. I've a macro written to pull in the data to the manufacturing schedule, but I need to execute the macro in the file automaticaly every 15 minutes, *but only while the user has the manufacturing schedule open*. I've tried using "Application.OnTime" with specific times, but this seems to open the manufacturing schdule if its closed . I'm pretty new to VBA so any assistance with the code would be much appreciated.  The code I'm using is pretty basic:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:00:30"), "Open_SFCDB"
'Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:16:30"), "Open_SFCDB"
'Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:32:30"), "Open_SFCDB"
'Application.OnTime TimeValue("08:48:30"), "Open_SFCDB"
'Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:04:30"), "Open_SFCDB"
......Etc, Etc for 24 hr period

'End Sub`
```

Comment: `OnTime` is a valid way to do this.  Post your code so we can help with why it opens the file when it shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

You might want to put your Application.OnTime procedure in a second workbook.  Have it check if your manufacturing schedule is open when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try and make it the active workbook and only proceed on success.

```
On Error Resume Next
Workbooks("ManufacturingSchedule").Activate
If Err <> 0 then
   .... do your update etc ....
end if
```

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for replying, as I say I'm pretty new to VBA, could you explain where the "On Error Resume Next....." code you suggested should put in my basic code (now included in my original question)